# How to count how many times each line appears in a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I have something like this

```
teithe.gr
List item
deitel.com
parinux.org
cs.vt.labs.edu
cs.may.ie
csse.monash.edu.au
amazon.com
amazon.com
teithe.gr
teithe.gr
```

I just want to know how can I count each word in an output like this

```
teithe.gr 3
amazon.com 2 
....etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sort inputfile | uniq -c
```

The output is not exactly as you specified:

```
      2 amazon.com
      1 cs.may.ie
      1 cs.vt.labs.edu
      1 csse.monash.edu.au
      1 deitel.com
      1 List item
      1 parinux.org
      3 teithe.gr
```

Comment: thanks it was what i was looking for

Comment: for some reason it says wait 4 min's il do that after the countdown